# Arrays and many errors

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, while-loop

No idea how to fix this. Throws out a different error every time I change something.

I have to create array A and B, both 10 numbers large. If k=0 I have to fill A with random numbers (0-20) and B with (50-100), if k is not equal to 0 then I have to calculate both arrays with the given formula.

And Last but not least, I have to create a third array `C= A[0] B[0] A [1] B[1]......`

Right now I'm dealing with this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: f != java.lang.Integer
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failConversion(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printFloat(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.PrintStream.format(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.PrintStream.printf(Unknown Source)
    at Ld3161rdb146.main(xxx.java:50)
```

Code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int A[] = new int [10];
        int B[] = new int [10];
        int K, i;
        float C;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Imants Kravalis 161RDB146");    
        System.out.print("K=");
        if (sc.hasNextInt())
            K = sc.nextInt();
        else {
            System.out.println("input-output error");
            sc.close();
            return;
        }
        sc.close();
        if (K ==0) 
        {
            Random r = new Random();
            i=0;
            while(i<10)
            {
                A[i] = r.nextInt()*0-21;
            B[i] = r.nextInt()*50-101;
            i++;
            }

        }
        else
            i=0;
            while(i<10)
            {A[i] = i+K;
             B[i] = (i+10)*K;
            i++;
            }




        System.out.println("A:");
        i=0;
        do{
            System.out.printf("%.1f\t", A[i]);
            i++;
        }while(i<10);

        System.out.println("B:");
        i=0;
        do{
            System.out.printf("%.1f\t", B[i]);
            i++;
        }while(i<10);

        for (i=0; i<20; i++) {
            C=A[i]&B[i];
            System.out.printf("%.1f\t", C);
        }



    }

}
```

Comment: 1.) Some [Recommended Reading](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and 2.) You seem to have a lot of misconceptions regarding what some of the symbols mean. You should (re)visit some basics.

Comment: Please don't bring your aggressive attitude here. I edited stuff out - we don't need to read your frustrations.

Answer (score 1):

A and B contains only integers, not floats.
on the row

```
System.out.printf("%.1f\t", A[i]);
```

you are trying to treat it as a float, change to "%d\t" and it will work.
See [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html) for reference.

Then you will get an array-index out of bounds from this:

```
 for (i=0; i<20; i++)
```

Since A and B only contains 10 elements, change 20 to 10.

Comment: You are my savior